# Different document types in different collections OR same collection without sharing fields?

Tags: solr, solr4

Using a single node Solr instance, I need to search for, lets say, electronics items & grocery items. But I never want to search both of them together. When I search for electrnoics I don't expect a grocery item ever & vice versa.

Should I be defining both these document types within a single schema.xml or should I use different collection for each of these two(maintaining separate schema.xml & solrconfig.xml for each of two) ?

I believe that if I add both to a single collection, without sharing fields among these two document types, I should be equally good as separating them in two collection(in terms of performance & all), as their indexes/filter caches would be totally independent of each other when they don't share fields?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only performance issue with defining both of these document in one schema is that:

1. your document size might get too big !
2. your index size will get big and searching it will be slower.

Comment: Aren't indexes for different fields maintained separately, I mean if I have two text fields both indexed separately within a schema, each of them would have its own set of indexes, so that if I one field's index is quite bigger it doesn't affect anyhow another unless I use both of the fields in one query ? Isn't it true ?!